# Uncomment smaller block inside commented block

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Is there a shortcut to only uncomment a small block inside another big commented one?

Example:

```
/*

foo1 {                      
 }             
foo2 {                    
}              
foo3 {         
}

*/
```

Then selecting `foo2` and pressing `ctrl-shift-/` would be good if it turns into:

```
/*
foo1 {
}
*/

foo2 {
}
/*

foo3 {
}
*/
```

Is there some customization to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own Live Template (`Preferences | Editor | Live Templates`).

Template text:

```
*/$SELECTION$/*
```

And set Applicable context to `Java | Comment`. Then you can use `Surround with Live Template...` (Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> Win/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) to uncomment a selection in a block comment.

Comment: Yeah, nice one! Didn't know this feature yet, very helpful :-) thanks